# Converting integer to string in dax and concatinate with left function

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I have a string (url) and a number (pagination), I need to concatenate them into a resulting URL.

I have search and looked at the VALUE and FORMAT dax functions but can't make it work in converting a number into a string. e.g.

thid is the sql code I'm trying to doing in dax :

```
CONCAT('http://test.com',LEFT(cast(col as string), 10))
```

Any Help please.

Comment: test_link = CONCATENATE("http://www.test.com", LEFT( FORMAT(col,""), 10))

Comment: The solution above worked for me.